# ex42.py LPTHW No out put

Tags: python-2.7

Respected Expert coders, Hello! I am absolutely new in the world of coding. I have started to learn python.I am using ZED Shah's LPTHW. For the first time I am stuck in the class section. I am attaching my code for rectification, please help me. The code is not giving any out put, simply back to prompt.

**Animal is-a object**

```
class Animal(object):
pass

class Dog(Animal):
def __init__(self, name):

    self.name = name

class Cat(Animal):    
def __init__(self, name):

    self.name = name

class Person(object):
def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name
    self.pet = None

class Employee(Person):
def __init__(self, name, salary):
    ## ?? hmm what is this strange magic?
    super(Employee, self).__init__(name)
    ## ??
    self.salary = salary

class Fish(object):
pass

class Salmon(Fish):
pass

class Halibut(Fish):
pass
```

## rover is- a Dog

```
rover = Dog("Rover")
satan = Cat("Satan")
mary = Person("Mary")
mary.pet = satan
frank = Employee("Frank", 120000)
frank.pet = rover
flipper = Fish()
crouse = Salmon()
harry = Halibut()
```

Comment: What sort of output are you expecting? There aren't any print statements, nor any return statements, so these would generally be expected to just return straight to the prompt.

Comment: Thanks, but tell me how I will use this code please.

Comment: dwanderson please help, how to use this code?

Comment: Sorry @myimran, I don't have LPTHW available, nor the time to figure out what it's asking. I've heard enough people mention LPTHW that I am guessing it should explain what is happening and what to expect.

Answer (score 0):

I have just gone through this exercise and all Zed wants is for you to familiarize yourself with "is-a" and "has-a" catch phrases. To differentiate between class, objects and variables. The code itself has no purpose other than as an exercise for your benefit.

Comment: This could be a comment. Not a full answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Comment: pyntree! thanks a lot, I highly appreciate your answer and help. can I email you in future? if so please your email address???